Speeding up Dataset.__getitems__
I have a model with a forward function that receives optional parameters, like this:
class MyModel(nn.Module):
  ...

  def forward(self, interactions: torch.Tensor, user_features: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None):
    """
      Where _N_ is the number of items

      interactions (Tensor): Nx2
      user_features (Tensor): Nx(number of features)
    """
    ...

For this reason, my Dataset also returns a dict, based on a DataFrame
class StackOverflowDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, user_features=None):
        self._data = data
        self._user_features = user_features

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if self._user_features is None:
            return {'interactions': self._data[idx]}
        else:
            return {
               'interactions': self._data[idx], 
               'user_features': self._user_features[self._data[idx]['user']]
            }

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

Most of the training time is spent on __getitem__, which makes me wonder: is having optional arguments on MyModel.forward bad practice? I guess most of the time is spent playing with numpy item by item, and then converting it to PyTorch's tensors and moving it to the GPU. Is there any way I can "pre-process" all of this beforehand but still use a Dataloader that returns a dict?
It seems that Datapipe also goes row by row. Would it be possible to directly return a dict with the whole 'interactions' tensor, and then the Dataloader slices it up?

EDIT: It seems DataPipe will be deprecated



having multiple arguments in forward is very common practice indeed.

How many workers are you using on the dataloader?

I don't think the number of workers is relevant. I'm not reading data from disk or doing heavy, parallelizable computations. The inefficiencies come from the software architecture.

It seems to be kind of a PyTorch caveat and open issue. Is just faster to do it "by hand" https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4959

How did you create/get the profiler image of your timings?

I used cProfile, which creates a .prof file that can be opened with a lot of viewers. In this case I used snakeviz. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

You could deifine __getitem__() as:
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return {
       'interactions': self._data[idx], 
       'user_features': self._user_features[self._data[idx]['user']] if self._user_features else None
        }

Is a little bit faster. But is not a definitive solution.
